# How to figure out the unit of measurement from table fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, area

I have a couple of fields with predefined values. In particular I have an 'area' field that I need to figure out its unit of measurement (e.g. km, miles, acres). What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: is this just an excel table? or a feature class

Answer (score 4):

The area unit is based on the Coordinate Reference System of the layer.

If you go to properties of the layer, click XY Coordinate System, then you will see a Linear Unit attribute.  This will be something like Foot, Meter, etc.

See below.  I know my version of ArcGIS is 10.2.1 but it's very close to the 10.0 layout:

[image]

Comment: This only applies if the features are in a geodatabase feature class. If the areas were added to a shapefile, they could be anything.

Comment: Additionally, someone may have added a new field and calculated acres, for example, even though the units are in meters.

Comment: Correct, I was basing this off of the fact the word "predefined" was used.  To me, this states the values are automatically being calculated, and therefore in a geodatabase.  Could predefined mean something else? Absolutely.

Comment: Good points @evv_gis.  This illustrates the need for well defined questions.

Comment: @evv_gis I read "predefined" as "they were in the data when I got it".

Comment: If the field in question is a default field that is managed by software and *is still in that format*, as pointed out this holds true. For any other case, you have to make an assumption. For example the field isn't updated anymore if you convert from a feature class to a shapefile, but it's still there. And any field added won't update, as well as the fact it could have been calculated to *any* unit regardless of CRS per Aaron's answer. The safest thing to do in any case is trust but verify, and in a case like this where you don't know the asker's experience, cover all bases.

Answer (score 4):

A featureclass in a geodatabase will automatically have a field called "Shape_Area".  The area is based off the coordinate system units.

However, very often you will encounter a field that someone has added to a featureclass or shapefile indicating an area measurement.  In this case, if there is no metadata, it is best to add a new field and calculate the area yourself in whichever units you would like.  You can do this by adding a field to the attribute table > right-click field > Calculate Geometry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Measure tool on a feature, changing units until you get a result that matches the value in the field.
If the field is the default shape.area, you can get it by checking units on the source tab of the properties page for the feature class.